# Need to send message twice in order to get a response

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When I have this code here:

```
    client.on("message", msg => {
    const args = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
    let second = args[1];
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * second) + 1);
    if(msg.content === "random") {
    msg.channel.send(`${x}`)
    console.log(x)
    console.log(second)
    }
    })
```

I need to send "random 10 (example)" twice and it still doesn't work cause it uses the "random" as the input for "second¨ how do i make this work?

Comment: Couldn't you just execute the random function again? I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: I get a NaN if I try to get a random number between 1-10 if I type  in random 10

Comment: Oh ok, you need to parse "second" as an integer I think because "msg" is a string.

Comment: when i do that i get this error: let "second" = args[1];
        ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: Oops! seems I explained it wrong. See my explanation as an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "msg" is a string, you need to parse it as an integer before preforming an operation on it. I recommend replacing the "let x" line with the following:

```
let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * parseInt(second)) + 1);
```

parseInt is an internal function that takes a string with number contents and turns it into an integer.

Comment: hey thanks for the help, still doesnt does anything when i send "random 10" or "random 100" etc. Is it something with the `if(msg.content === "random")` ?

Comment: @Jordydev Does "msg" contain the whole input (ex. random 100) or just the first word (ex. random)? If it does you need to parse just the "random" part

Comment: where do i need to parse the random part? it is btw ex.random

Comment: @Jordydev  Sorry, so just to clarify, does it include the whole input string? or just the first word

Comment: only the first word "random"

Comment: i think i found a solution: im gonna use `const triggerWords = ['banana', 'fire', 'white'];

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return false;

  triggerWords.forEach((word) => {
    if (message.content.includes(word)) {
      message.reply("banana");
    }
  });
});` but then with my code combined :)

Comment: @Jordydev If msg only includes the first word, then what are you reading in args? There wouldn't be anything there since msg only holds one thing

Comment: @Jordydev Alright, do whatever works best for you! :)

Comment: `const triggerWords = ['random', 'Random'];

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return false;
  const args = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
    let second = args[1];
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * parseInt(second)) + 1);

  triggerWords.forEach((word) => {
    if (msg.content.includes(word)) {
      msg.reply(`${x}`);
    }
  });
});` It workt! Thanks alot you helped me alot with a simple code lmao :)

Comment: @Jordydev Of course! Do you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const triggerWords = ['random', 'Random'];

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return false;
  const args = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
    let second = args[1];
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * parseInt(second)) + 1);

  triggerWords.forEach((word) => {
    if (msg.content.includes(word)) {
      msg.reply(`${x}`);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to quandale dingle's answer, what you can do with your bot is to create a command handler, which will make the developing process much easier and will look nice. If you don't really want to create a command handler, you can also use the following code:

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
        //set a prefix before, and include this if statement in the on message
          const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
          const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase()
        //use if statements for each command, make sure they are nested inside the startsWith statement
        }
```

---

If you want to create a command handler, there's some sample code below. It works on discord.js v13, but I've no idea if it will work in v12. This is a more advanced command handler.

```
 /*looks for commands in messages & according dependencies
 or command handler in more simple terms*/
 const fs = require("fs");
 const prefix = "+"; //or anything that's to your liking
 client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 fs.readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
 const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) =>
       file.endsWith(".js")
 ); //subfolders, like ./commands/helpful/help.js

 //alternatively... for a simpler command handler
 fs.readdirSync("./commands/").filter((file) =>
    file.endsWith(".js")
 );
 for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const commandName = file.split(".")[0]
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(commandName, command);
 }
 });
    
    
    
 //looks for commands in messages
 client.on("messageCreate", message => {
 if (message.author == client.user) return;
 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
    if (!command) return;
    command.run(client, message, args)
 }
 });
```